# Azure - terraform - can't deploy function apps, name always wrong

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-functions

TLDR; my Terraform reference name was wrong

I'm deploying a function app using Terraform, to Azure.
I'm using this code:

```
 resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "function app" {
  name                = "testfunction13515"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.automation_rg.name
  location            = var.location

  site_config {}
}
```

I'm always getting following error:

```
 Error: Invalid resource name
 
   on main.tf line 194, in resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "function app":
  194:  resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "function app" {
 
 A name must start with a letter or underscore and may contain only letters,
 digits, underscores, and dashes.
```

I've tried deploying it with this name in the portal, and there, the name is not an issue.
I also tried the linux variant, same issue.
I'm using the latest terraform and azurerm versions.
Could this be a bug?
I saw there were some azure function app bug fixes in the latest few new azurerm versions...

Comment: It's not about the name of the function app within azure, but the name of the resource within terraform's state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resource name shouldn't have space. So inctead of:

```
resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "function app"
```

it should be

```
resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "function_app"
```

Comment: oh wow, I've been looking over this typo for a long time! thanks